# Woocommerce edit checkout layout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How do i change the layout of my checkout page in Wordpress?

Illustration: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0bFhT.png
[image]

This is what my checkout page looks like. (Image is cropped)

I want to position the blue box under the red, and the green box where they blue box was.

But i have no idea how to approach this.

I can't find any file that define the positions.

Comment: you really need the file, otherwise you are going to have to do fixed positions in css. There is defintely a file within the application that adds this page, it could be the active theme or child theme or a plugin.

Comment: I think it must be within here somewhere: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/tree/master/templates
I know my theme files override these, but i need to find the original file, so i can create a new in my child theme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file is form-checkout.php
https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/templates/checkout/form-checkout.php


The codes that determinates the marked boxes are:

```
<h3 id="order_review_heading"><?php _e( 'Your order', 'woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review' ); ?>
```

Move them around as pleased.